# How to get user.field value in node--teaser.twig

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

That's how I getting user.field value for node--full.twig but this code does not work for node--teaser.twig

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
              $variables['author'] = $node->getOwner()->field_name->value;
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit's the problem:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')
```

Even if that returned a value, it would probably be the wrong one; it's not common to render the node as a teaser on its own view page.

As it happens, you don't need to load it yourself for any of the view modes. The node is already in `$variables`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['author'] = $variables['node']->getOwner()->field_name->value;
}
```

You may need to add a further check of `$variables['node']->getType()` if the field is only available to certain content types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `$variables['author'] = $variables['node']->getOwner()->field_name->value;` and `$variables['author'] = $variables['node']->getType()->$variables['node']->getOwner()->field_name->value;` not works.

Comment: I take my words back. Everything works perfectly! Thank you!